# trace inequality with symmetric Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

Let $A, B$ be two positive semi-definite $n \times n$ matrices and let $L$ be an $n \times n$ matrix that satisfies $\rho(L) < 1$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes spectral radius.

Let $A \otimes B$ denote the regular Kronecker product and let $A \otimes_s B$ denote the symmetric Kronecker product as defined in Definition 3.3 [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf).

Define:
$$
\begin{align*}
T_1 &= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}( (I - L \otimes L)^{-1} (A \otimes B + B \otimes A)  (I - L \otimes L)^{-T} ) \:, \\
T_2 &= \mathrm{tr}( (I - L \otimes_s L)^{-1} (A \otimes_s B)  (I - L \otimes_s L)^{-T} ) \:.
\end{align*}
$$

I can prove that $T_2 \leq T_1$ always holds. I'm curious if it is possible to prove a reverse inequality, that $T_1 \leq C \cdot T_2$ for some absolute constant $C > 0$ that does not depend on $A, B, L, n$. In doing some simulations, I found that $C \geq 2$ was never violated. But I don't know how to prove this.

Edit: For instance, if $L = \rho \cdot I$ for some $|\rho| < 1$ and $A = B = I$, then it is not hard to see that the constant $C = n^2 / (n(n+1)/2) \leq 2$ works. More generally, if $L = \rho \cdot I$ and $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, this bound $C \leq 2$ also works.  Another case where $C \leq 2$ works is if $L$ is symmetric and $A=B=I$.